# How to convert JSON documents to Parquet/ORC file

Tags: database, parquet, orc

Is it possible to convert JSON to Parquet/ORC format?

I have converted CSV/TSV data into Parquet the following steps in HIVE

```
1: Create an external HIVE Table with TSV data source and TSV serde.
2: Create a normal HIVE table with Parquet serde.
3: INSERT INTO ParquetTable SELECT * FROM ParquetTable.
```

So the question is, is there a similar way I can convert JSON to Parquet or do I need to flatten the JSON data first?

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done using the Apache Spark library.

Pre-requisites: Data should be single-lined JSON. Since Spark DataSource library doesn't support multi-line  JSON.

Below is the Sample code using Spark 2.x :

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local")
  .getOrCreate()

val inpDF = spark.read.json("<inputPath>")
// Auto schema Inference 
inpDF.printSchema()
inpDF.write.parquet("<outputPath>")
```

Single Lined JSON : `{"Device":{"Brand":"Apple","Model":"Iphone11Pro"}}`

Multi Lined JSON : `{
   "Device": {
      "Brand":"Apple",
      "Model":"Iphone11Pro"
   }
 }`

Comment: What do you mean when you say data should be single-lined JSON? Do you mean flat without in nesting and lists in it?

Comment: JSON can be nested upto any level. I have added an example in answer.

Answer (score 0):

This python library worked for me: https://github.com/noirello/pyorc. A code snippet is given as follows (borrowed from the library's README.md)

```
import pyorc

with open("./new_data.orc", "wb") as data:
    with pyorc.Writer(data, "struct<col0:int,col1:string>") as writer:
        writer.write((1, "ORC from Python"))
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting @BNazaruk. I don't understand why this is not an answer to the question, could you please point it out? It would be great if you could let me know how I can improve the above answer.

Comment: You're right. It does work. It didn't work outside of the context, which is how our validation is offered to be conducted. Sorry about it.